# Resolving a circular reference in c++ header files

Tags: c++

I am encountering a circular include reference error where I wish to use an object of type Deck in CardFactory, and an object of type CardFactory in Deck. Any hints as to how to fix this problem?

```
//CardFactory.h
#ifndef CARDFACTORY_H
#define CARDFACTORY_H

#include "Deck.h"

#include <string>

using std::string;

class CardFactory {

public:
    Deck getDeck();
    static CardFactory* getFactory() {
        static CardFactory singleton;
        return &singleton;
    }

};

#endif

//Deck.h
#ifndef DECK_H
#define DECK_H

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "CardFactory.h"
using std::ostream;

class Deck : public std::vector<Card*> {
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Deck& dt);
    Card* draw();
    Deck(CardFactory* cf);
};

#endif
```

Comment: You should not inherit from vector and other STL containers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forward reference (or forward declaration).

In `Deck.h` you don't need to `#include "CardFactory.h"`, instead just declare the class.

```
class CardFactory;
```

This should work because in `Deck` class you are only using pointer to class `CardFactory`

Comment: Also called "forward declaration"

Comment: @MichaelAlbers that's true